# How to update object with given values, if not all object keys are provided

Tags: typescript

If i have a given object, of type user:

**User Object**

```
{
        id: 001,
        email: 'test.user@example.com',
        password: '$2a$05$LhayLxezLhK1LhWvKxCyLOj0j1u.Kj0jZ0pEmm134uzrQlFvQJLF6',
        firstname: 'Test',
        lastname: 'User',
        lastlogin: null,
        authfailures: 0,
        disabled: false,
        confirmed: true,
        permissions: [],
        groups: [],
        emailNotifications: false
}
```

And I also have another object, in this instance returned from a form, with which I want to update the attributes of the above user object:

**Form Results**

```
{
    email: 'test.user2@example.com',
    firstname: 'Updated',
    lastname: 'Updated2',
    groups: ['test', 'test2']
}
```

How can I update the values in the user object using the form's returned values without setting each attribute manually? I want the user value to then have these values:

**Desired Result**

```
{
        id: 001,
        email: 'test.user2@example.com',
        password: '$2a$05$LhayLxezLhK1LhWvKxCyLOj0j1u.Kj0jZ0pEmm134uzrQlFvQJLF6',
        firstname: 'Updated',
        lastname: 'Updated2',
        lastlogin: null,
        authfailures: 0,
        disabled: false,
        confirmed: true,
        permissions: [],
        groups: ['test', 'test2'],
        emailNotifications: false
}
```

Without having to do this:

```
user.firstname = formResults.firstname
user.lastname = formResults.lastname
user.email = formResults.email
user.groups = formResults.groups
```

Is there a method I can use to patch over the given attributes?

Comment: Does it help the usage of `Object.assign()` from Javascript?

Comment: @davidmpaz, stumbled on that just after I posted. It's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found I can use `Object.assign()`.

Like this: `Object.assign(user, formResults);`

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 0):

You can use deconstructs:

```js
const baseObject = {
        id: 001,
        email: 'test.user@example.com',
        password: '$2a$05$LhayLxezLhK1LhWvKxCyLOj0j1u.Kj0jZ0pEmm134uzrQlFvQJLF6',
        firstname: 'Test',
        lastname: 'User',
        lastlogin: null,
        authfailures: 0,
        disabled: false,
        confirmed: true,
        permissions: [],
        groups: [],
        emailNotifications: false
};

const newProps = {
    email: 'test.user2@example.com',
    firstname: 'Updated',
    lastname: 'Updated2',
    groups: ['test', 'test2']
}

const updatedObject = {
    ...baseObject,
    ...newProps
};
```

You can also do the same on `baseObject` but I would recommend keeping your code immutable.